# I cannot run Gurobi in C++(Clion, Mac OS)

Tags: c++, clion, gurobi

I am trying to run the latest Gurobi version in my laptop. I installed it and got accessed to the newest license..

When I was trying to run the baby example. It told me that

fatal error: 'gurobi_c++.h' file not found

I believe there may be some initialisation thing to do. However, I cannot find it in their documentation. Can anyone help me about this?   Thank you very much

Comment: What platform and C++ compiler are you using?

Comment: I use CLion, the C++ compiler is cmake?   It seems that Clion would let cmake to detect what is the complier.. I didnot change on the choice of complier, just use the default one.

Comment: @Ethanabc CMake is a meta-build-system, *not* a compiler. `gcc`/`g++`/`clang`/`clang++`/`cl.exe` etc, are compilers. CLion is an IDE that uses a real compiler under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

1- Be sure that you installed gurobi.

2- You need to run the following command line.

g++ "filename" -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 -o "outputfilename" -I "path to the include folder of your gurobi" -L "path to the lib folder of your gurobi" -lgurobi_c++ "your gurobi version".

3- Then run the output file as follows:

./"outfilename"

For instance in my case, I first ran the following command:

g++ bilinear.cpp -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 -o blinear -I /Library/gurobi1001/macos_universal2/include -L /Library/gurobi1001/macos_universal2/lib -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi100

Then, I ran the following command.

./blinear